# HTTP POST Request URI too long

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to post a photo on facebook using a post request. FB needs the photograph in multipart/form data. I am using hte following code

```
string data = String.Format("Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundarySkAQdHysJKel8YBM\n\n------WebKitFormBoundarySkAQdHysJKel8YBM\nContent-Disposition: form-data;name=\"fileUpload\"; filename=\"y1.jpg\"\nContent-Type: image/jpeg");
            var FB = new Facebook.FacebookClient(pagetoken);              
            byte[] bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\a.jpg");
            string encoded = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
            data += "----WebKitFormBoundarySkAQdHysJKel8YBM\n\n"+encoded;                
            dynamic parameters = new ExpandoObject();
            parameters.message = "sdsad";
            parameters.source = data;
            FB.Post("me/photos", parameters);
```

But when I runn it, it says URI too long. What else can be done?

Comment: use Image url insted of posting all image in request ..

Comment: My guess is that the SDK that you are using are doing something wrong. The length of the Post data shouldn't effect the URI length

Comment: It looks like that's sending the image in the URI as query string parameters instead of the POST body

Comment: @lgy : Facebook says Capture a photo via file upload as multipart/form-data then use the source parameter. So I guess what is means is we need to pass the data in the uri itself or does it mean something else? https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/page/photos/